# How can I get exchange user from LegacyExchangeDN address?

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, exchange-server

so, i have a an active session and a GAL.

i have an exchange address: **/o=My-Org/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=My Name**

and i want to get address entry from that address (eventually i'm trying to find the SMTP address).

the only thing i managed to do is this:

```
rcpAddress.Session.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries[@"My Name"]
```

this got me the correct address, but this gave me the same result aswell:

```
rcpAddress.Session.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries[@"My Name"]
rcpAddress.Session.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries[@"My Name gsdg"]
rcpAddress.Session.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries[@"My Na"]
```

so this doesn't look like a great way of achiving it...
i know that the above excahnge address is unique, and i'd like to search the entry from that.

i can do a disgusting workaround and check if my result address equals to the input, but what if there are duplicate results - i can get the wrong one.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the EX type address, you can programmatically construct the entry id; its format is documented.

```
abFlags[0]: 00
abFlags[1]: 00
abFlags[2]: 00
abFlags[3]: 00
muid: MUIDEMSAB
ulVersion: 0x00000001
ulType: 0x00000000 (DT_MAILUSER)
szAddr: /o=Swiftpage/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=0b3e51186fb04360b84f67d65c35e23a-SomeUser
```